# How to pass an array of Pointer types to RttiMethods.Invoke in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

Using Delphi 10.2 with latest update

I have a procedure (actual code):

```
PyObject = packed record ... end;
PPyObject = ^PyObject
PPyObjectArray = array of PPyObject;

procedure invokeMethod (methodName : string; args : PPyObjectArray);
var  ctx: TRttiContext;
     rt : TRttiType;
     mt : TRttiMethod;
     py : TPyArithmetic;
     tv : array of TValue;
begin
   py := TPyArithmetic.Create;
   ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
   try
     rt := ctx.GetType(TPyArithmetic);
     mt := rt.GetMethod (methodName);

    setlength (tv, 1);
    tv[0].From(args);
    mt.Invoke(py, tv);
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The code itself is spread out within invokeMethod onto multiply lines for debugging reasons.  The purpose of the procedure is to call the method methodName with the argument array args. However I have been unable to successfuly get the arguments across to the invoked method. Although the correct function is invoked the arguments at entry to the invoked method are garbled. My question is how should I pass an array of T to the invoke method?

I also tried calling invoke using

mt.Invoke(py, [args]);

but I get the compile error:

E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Invoke' that can be called with these arguments.

Tried

mt.Invoke(py, [@args]);

but I get the runtime error:

EInvalidCast with message 'Invalid case typecast', tried to trace the call but didn't succeed in figuring out why I got the error.

The code on the invoked side is:

```
class function TPyArithmetic.add (args : PPyObjectArray) : double;
begin
   result := TArithmetic.add (GetPythonEngine.PyFloat_AsDouble (args[0]), GetPythonEngine.PyFloat_AsDouble (args[1]));
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, I doubt that PyObject should be packed. It won't affect the layout, and they are all allocated dynamically so it won't affect alignment. But still......

Comment: These types came from another third party library. I wanted to show exactly how the other library defined these types in case it had a bearing on the problem.

Comment: Sure. It's one of the reasons I don't use that library. I don't trust it.

Comment: It would be helpful to actually see the code of the invoked method to tell if the invokation via RTTI is doing what it should apart from the obvious defect that David pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Updated question to show invoked code. Note I'm stil exploring this way of doing things and the code you see isn't the final code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TValue.From` is a function that returns a new value. A this code is wrong:

```
tv[0].From(args);
```

Nothing is ever assigned to `tv[0]`. You need to do that like so:

```
tv[0] := TValue.From(args);
```

Simpler though is to remove the dynamic array and use an open array constructor:

```
mt.Invoke(py, [TValue.From(args)]);
```

And the code that creates and destroys the RTTI context is spurious also. It works fine your way but it could equally be:

```
procedure invokeMethod(methodName: string; args: PPyObjectArray);
var  
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rt: TRttiType;
  mt: TRttiMethod;
  py: TPyArithmetic;
begin
  py := TPyArithmetic.Create;  
  rt := ctx.GetType(TPyArithmetic);
  mt := rt.GetMethod (methodName);
  mt.Invoke(py, [TValue.From(args)]);
end;
```

FWIW, it looks like your code leaks `py`.

Comment: This might very well explain why I'm not getting anything at the other end. I'll try this tomorrow. I realized py leaked. I assume methods like GetType are class methods which is why we don't need to call create on ctx.

Comment: No. That's not it. RTTI context lifetime management is just weird. It auto creates itself relying on managed type initialization.